# login form for iphone

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios4, titanium

im developing an app in Titanium Developer, im trying to make a login form so that the users can authenticate through my app to my server so they can get info regarding their respecting user, any help would be appreciated ;)

Comment: can you be more specific? e.g. what system is running on your server, what format are you using for exchanging the data (JSON, XML..)

Comment: im getting the info from SAP through JSON

Comment: this really helped me... chek it out.. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-user-authentication/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if the endpoint already exists as a webservice, and you are running HTTPS on the server, then the tutorial link provided above should be sufficient.

i personally think for an enterprise application  that has a controlled audience, you don't really need to go the oAuth direction.

Answer (score 0):

you should encrypt your connection to your server with [oauth](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849). here is an [example](http://ziodave.tumblr.com/post/746024933/titanium-implementation-of-twitter-oauth).

Answer (score 0):

in OAuth there are 3 points involved, "the user, the consumer and the provider...
easy example:
facebook speaking...
the user would be us (you, me and the mortals...)
the consumer: any app (from a different development company other than facebook, third party apps)
provider: facebook

in my company..
the user: (the mortals... you and me)
the consumer: an app developed by my company
provider: my company

OAuth was developed so that the third party apps didn't have access to the whole base company database, only certain information about the users regarding the provider DB.

Thats why it generates different types of token so that the third party apps dont get your password or mails or any stuff you dont whant that people outside facebook to se, that token is the one who authenticates the app to have access to certain info regarding the user.

when it comes to my company, im the provider and the consumer, my company database access is only for the company development team. nobody outside my company has access to de DB.

in conclusion: OAuth is the greatest auth protocol ever, but... does your company really needs it?? is there someone outside your company using your resources??  is there a third party development? thats the real question...

to make my point clearer, check out how many providers are compared to clients, every tutorial has always the same few providers: Facebook,twitter,google,yahoo etc...

check out how many clients are?? there must be at least a million or a billion or a number we cant pronounce  (every app developed for Facebook twitter or google has strictly instructions to be authenticated trough OAuth

thats why im not using OAuth for the near present...